# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: (Class not found exceptionnn)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring. Just finished core and j2ee and started MVC but I am getting this error. Can someone help me out to rectify this. Thanks in advance

This is my web.xml file

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

  <display-name>MVC_HelloWorld1</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>helloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>helloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ds</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

this page is getting displayed but when I am trying to click the submit button I am getting bean creation exception.

**index.jsp**

```
 <form action="./hello.ds" >

    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="sayHello">
 </form>
```

**helloWorld-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"></bean>
  <bean name="/hello.ds"  class="/MVC_HelloWorld1/src/controller/HelloController"/>
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prifix" value="/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

I am not sure but I am thinking that the problem is with this HelloController.

**HelloController.java**

```
package controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class HelloController implements Controller {
@Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {
        String name=req.getParameter("name");
        Map m=new HashMap();
        m.put("msg","hello..."+name);
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("success",m);
        return mav;     
    }
}
```

**success.jsp**

```
${msg}
```

Stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/helloWorld-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [/MVC_HelloWorld1/src/controller/HelloController] for bean with name 'd' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/helloWorld-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /MVC_HelloWorld1/src/controller/HelloController
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [/MVC_HelloWorld1/src/controller/HelloController] for bean with name 'd' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/helloWorld-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /MVC_HelloWorld1/src/controller/HelloController
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please post your compete stack trace

Comment: Bean name cannot be hello.ds

Comment: Are your following any tutorial for it?

Comment: Please follow the below tutorial http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/

Comment: how do i add complete stack trace. Sorry I am even new to stackoverflow

Comment: Did u follow any tutorial for it?

Comment: yeah I am following durga soft videos and also referring javatpoint sometimes.

Comment: Change your class in hello servert.xml to controller.Hellocontroller

Comment: I even did that but its the same error.

Comment: <bean name="/hello.ds" class="controller.Hellocontroller"/>   same error with this statement too.

Comment: bean name cannot be hello.ds?? Then  how do I give it ? I am matching the bean name with url pattern right?

Comment: Change your bean name to hello. I think you are confusing it with the request mapping

Comment: Bean name is different from request mapping

Comment: Can you please follow the tutorial link I provided. I think there are couple of issues with your configs. Follow the tutorial and change as per your requirements

Comment: The same error still

Comment: You are also missing couple of annotations as well . It will better to start form scratch and go from there

Comment: Okay lemme try. Thank you

Comment: Let me know if it still does not work

Comment: I fixed all your formatting.  Please [edit] your post to examine the markdown and learn the correct way to format code and stack traces.

Comment: @ Jim GarrisonSure Jim. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix the following parts in your `helloWorld-servlet.xml`. The class name of a bean should be `controller.HelloController`. And there is a typo in your bean property, it should be `prefix`.

```
...
<bean name="/hello.ds"  class="controller.HelloController"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
...
```

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'a' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/helloWorld-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [controller.HelloController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a problem in helloWorld-servlet.xml. Try replacing  class="/MVC_HelloWorld1/src/controller/HelloController" with
class="controller/HelloController".